# na.omit in data.table, R

Tags: r, data.table, na

This could be a potential bug and I'm having difficulty reproducing it using a standalone example, however, maybe the error message might be helpful to digging to the bottom of it. `miv` is a `data.table`:

```
> str(miv)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  113534 obs. of  21 variables:
 $ ym            : num  1980 1980 1980 1980 1980 ...
 $ dte           : Date, format: "1980-03-31" "1980-03-31" ...
 $ xs_ret        : num  -16.3 -16.3 -16.3 14.3 14.3 ...
 $ xs_mkt        : num  -8.85 -8.85 -8.85 12.77 12.77 ...
 $ smb           : num  -7.23 -7.23 -7.23 3.62 3.62 ...
 $ hml           : num  0.966 0.966 0.966 0.318 0.318 ...
 $ umd           : num  3.713 3.713 3.713 -0.762 -0.762 ...
 $ wficn         : num  100567 101394 102565 100010 100019 ...
 $ iv_w          : num [1:113534, 1] -1.039 -0.571 -0.831 -0.357 -0.263 ...

> miv <- na.omit(miv)
Error in `[.data.table`(object, !omit) : 
   i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of     elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please let datatable-help know if you'd     like this, or add your comments to FR #1611.
```

Comment: Can you at least show how you created the `iv_w` column?

Comment: Unfortunately there is about 100 lines of code that create that column

Answer (score 3):

If it's not reproducible, it's too localized:

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
DT[3, 2] <- NA
DT[4, 3] <- NA
DT
#   x  y  v
#1: a  1  1
#2: a  3  2
#3: a NA  3
#4: b  1 NA
#5: b  3  5
#6: b  6  6
#7: c  1  7
#8: c  3  8
#9: c  6  9
na.omit(DT)
#   x y v
#1: a 1 1
#2: a 3 2
#3: b 3 5
#4: b 6 6
#5: c 1 7
#6: c 3 8
#7: c 6 9
```

Comment: yes, i have done this on my own as well. however, i have encountered this several times already so wanted to see if someone else ran into this

Comment: That is what the datatable-help list is _for_

Comment: happy to send it to the list instead.

Comment: I think that is a better place for troubleshooting specific problems like this.  When you do, if you can provide any more color about how you created that column, I think it will be helpful.

Comment: even `dput(head(miv))` would be helpful